# Stop Autoscroll content removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code, that I created to highlight the problem I'm having.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.p {
   position:relative;
   border:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:blue;
   width:300px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   min-height:100px;
}

.c {
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   border:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   width:300px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content {
   display:none;
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   for(var count=0; count < 50; count++) 
      $("#id1").append("<div class=\"p\"><button class=\"b\">click</button><div class=\"content\"></div></div>");
});

$(document).on("click",".b",function(event) {

   // empty all contents
   $(".p >.content").empty().hide();

   // generage a random number between 10 and 60
   var random=Math.floor(Math.random() * (60 - 10 + 1)) + 10;

   for(var count=0; count < random; count++)
      $(this).parent("div").children(".content").append("<div class=\"c\"></div>");

   $(this).parent("div").children(".content").show();

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="id1"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click the buttons it adds content to the  selected. It also empties the content of any other divs so that the content shown is exclusive to that selected. The problem is that if I click to add content under an already selected div when the content is removed it autoscrolls up (because of the collapsing div) and loses the location of where the user just selected. What I want to happen is for the content to hide like normal, however not move scroll location. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?